# How to map two class properties based on Customer

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core, shopify

I have an application in which I am getting Shopify orders via Shopify webhooks. Now I have an issue is when I have only one client I mapped Shopify to receive an order via the traditional way with object properties and save it into the database.

Now I got two more clients and all clients want to map class fields according to them.

Let's suppose I got a Shopify order object with the following details:

```
{
        "id": 4655316533326,
        "checkout_id": 29212941516878,
        "user_id": 71894499406,
        "note": "hello world",
        "subtotal_price_set": {
            "shop_money": {
                "amount": "109.00",
                "currency_code": "USD"
            }
        "total_tax": "0.00",
        "total_tax_set": {
            "shop_money": {
                "amount": "0.00",
                "currency_code": "USD"
            },
            "presentment_money": {
                "amount": "0.00",
                "currency_code": "USD"
            }
        }

}
```

I have a class name Order as well in my application which contains some of the following properties:

```
public class Order {

    public string OrderNo { get; set; }
    public string DebtorID { get; set; }
    public virtual string DeliveryAddress1 { get; set; }
    public virtual string DeliveryAddress2 { get; set; }
    public virtual string RIRTNo { get; set; }
    public List<OrderLine> Lines { get; set; }
    public string OrderNote { get; set; }
    Public Customer Customer { get; set; }

}
```

Now some customers want me to map shopify order `Note` property with mine `Order.Customer.Note`

and one want to map that `Note` proerty with `Order.Note`

same with `OrderNo`. One wants to map it directly with Order.OrderNo and others want to map it with ``RIRTNo```

How to handle this kind of situation?

I created one table on the database to keep this mapping information.

I can get the customer detail from the Shopify order and then I make the DB query to get map information but the problem is in the database the detail is in dictionary like structure.

Consider this below mapping info for x Customer:
the key is a Shopify object property

```
"Order": {
"note": "Customer.Note"
"Id": "OrderId"
}
```

the `key` is the Shopify property name and the `value` is my application object name but I can't figure out how to make them based on this info.

Comment: could you share the way you make the mapping now so that will show us how to help more clearly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can make a web form to admin this task

we need a table we will call it **MappingInfo** table.

[image]

The idea is for 1 field you have 2 or 3 options to map it with the other class

so you will insert into this table all your customer's mapping options

after that, you will use the Automapper like this

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(GetMapperConfigurationExpression());
var _mapper = config.CreateMapper();

private MapperConfigurationExpression GetMapperConfigurationExpression(Int customerId)
{
    MapperConfigurationExpression mapperConfiguraitonExpression = new MapperConfigurationExpression();  

    // Get Data From MappingInfo Table where MappingInfo.customerId == customerId "from the parameters" and MappingInfo.PropertyName == "AppId"
    
    if (MappingInfo.OptionId==1)
      mapperConfiguraitonExpression.CreateMap<srcMyClass, destMyClass>().ForPath(dest => dest.AppId.Code, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.InvoiseId))
      
    if (MappingInfo.OptionId==2)
      mapperConfiguraitonExpression.CreateMap<srcMyClass, destMyClass>().ForPath(dest => dest.AppId.Code, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.LogecalId))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, this depends on the Customer's mind.

So if you don't have any way to mapping yet.

you can divide your customers into 3 or 4 groups or more.

then you can use a factory design pattern
or simply can use an "if" statement depending on a new field "CustomerGroupId" and this should come with the entity to your code

Then:

```
if (Customer.CustomerGroupId == 1)
{
 // do mapping like Order.Note = shopify.Note
}
else if (Customer.CustomerGroupId == 1)
{
 // do mapping like Order.Customer.Note = shopify.Note
}
```

Comment: what if you have 50+ customers ?

Comment: you cant group them to 5 group or something like that  ?

Comment: I just share this one class example I have more than 20+ classes and I need to map them

Comment: I will create a web form for customers to set the mapping info

Comment: what about automapper did you try to make use of it ?

Comment: can you share any examples to do like this kind of this using automapper?

Comment: are you using c# and dot net core  ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249569/discussion-between-saghar-francis-and-mohm-zanaty).

Answer (score 0):

A very simple option is to use the "mapping info" within the `Order` class, and then modify the `OrderNote` property to use the mapping for getting/setting the note.

For example, create a method that provides the mapping:

```cs
private string _map = "note"; // default value when SetMap is not used

public void SetMap(string map)
    => _map = map;
```

And then `OrderNote` becomes:

```cs
private string _note;

public string OrderNote { 
    get => GetNote();
    set => SetNote(value);
}

private string GetNote()
{
    if(_map == "note") return _note;
        
    if(_map == "Customer.Note") return Customer.Note;
    
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Invalid _map");
}

private void SetNote(string value)
{
    if(_map == "note") { _note = value; return; }
        
    if(_map == "Customer.Note") { Customer.Note = value; return; }
    
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Invalid _map");
}
```

Use the same pattern for each type of mapping.